# flutter API request for sign in users

Tags: android, flutter, api, request, flutter-web

I am new to Flutter and API requests.
There is an issue that I am confused with, I am creating a log in page with Flutter and I have a URL for authentication users. I was seeing some samples and all of them used POST requests to the URL with the body of username and password. But I think it should be a GET request.
Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks.

Comment: if the endpoint demand a POST request you have to call the endpoint with POST request.

Comment: @SaiedIslamShuvo But the nature of log in is a GET request. How can it be a POST request in the endpoint?

Comment: if you are sending the user & password to login into the app, the correct way is POST. Other thing is get the user like "/api/users/{userId}" or /api/me to get the profile of authenticated user.

Comment: @FrancoBerardi thank you, but I don't understand the logic behind it. 
In swagger UI I have a GET request with parameters of username and password. I tried both GET and POST requests, but the POST request gives me the correct output while in swagger UI it's a GET request.

Comment: When you are logging in the user, you are CREATING a session/token. Then the following request will be authorized with that token.. I don't sea anything wrong to make the request a post. Maybe you can add more information regarding swagger..

Comment: @FrancoBerardi now that makes sense, thank you